# Add sku to product url in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add product SKU to my products url in WooCommerce like this example :

> example.com/product/sku/productname

I checked [this topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/custom-field-values-in-permalink/3517#3517), but in this method sku will add to end of product name not used as I want : **product/sku/productname**

Answer (score 1):

you have to add "sku" text url or product actual sku like your product name is pen and sku was pen-1 so you want product/pen-1/pen/ or product/sku/pen
please specify this